# Github: is it possible to send a message to all the people watching a project?

Tags: open-source, project-management, github

In Github, is it possible to send a message to all the people watching a project? I'm looking for help maintaining my project, and I thought the people watching the development might make good candidates.

Comment: Off topic, not dealing with coding but how the interface/messaging work, better off to GitHub:Support

Comment: @random of course it's on topic, Github is a major tool for many programmers. Anyways I got my answer, you were too late to close my question :-p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible currently, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

It was made even more impossible now that private messaging has been removed on April 3, 2012.

> Today we're removing Private Messaging from GitHub. If you want people
>   to contact you, please provide a [public email address for your
>   profile](https://github.com/settings/profile).

Spring Cleaning:

https://github.com/blog/1091-spring-cleaning/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to write your own script to do this. *[Automatically send messages to all forkers of your Github repo](http://aelogica.com/tutorial/automatically-send-messages-to-all-forkers-of-your-github-repo/)* may be a good starting point.